# How to pass the dataframe along list in dash framework?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, plotly-dash

I'm trying to pass the data frame and selected property of a dropdown to the different calling function in dash. I'm able to pass selected value but i don't get data frame. Here is my code.

```
"""Visualization graph"""
import os
from flask import Flask
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


DIRECTORY_PATH = 'C:/Users/fortu/Desktop/Zuhair/'

directories = [
    d for d in (os.path.join(DIRECTORY_PATH, directories) for directories in
                os.listdir(DIRECTORY_PATH))
    if os.path.isdir(d)
]

external_stylesheets = [
    'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css'
]


# Normally, Dash creates its own Flask server internally. By creating our own,
# we can create a route for downloading files directly:
server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(dbc.Col(
            html.Div("Ground truth visualization",
                     style={'textAlign': 'center',
                            'color': 'red', 'fontSize': '40px'}),
            md=12)),
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([
                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Row(dcc.Dropdown(
                            id='selected-dir',
                            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i}
                                     for i in directories],
                            placeholder="Select the directory"),
                            style={
                                'marginLeft': '25px',
                                'display': 'inline-block',
                                'width': '90%'
                            }
                        )), width=2),
                        dbc.Col(children=[
                            html.Div(dbc.Row(dcc.Dropdown(
                                id='selected-csv-fields',
                                placeholder="Select the field"),
                                style={
                                    'display': 'inline-block',
                                    'width': '90%'
                                }
                            )),
                            html.Div(dbc.Row(id='intermediate-value'), style={'display': 'none'})
                        ], width=2),
                    ]),
                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col(html.Div([
                            dbc.Row(
                                [dbc.Col(html.Div(
                                    dcc.Graph(id='line-graph'),
                                    className='bg-dark badge-dark'))]),
                            dbc.Row([dbc.Col(html.Div(
                                dcc.Graph(id='stack-graph'),
                                className='bg-warning'))],
                                className="row mt-3")]), width=5)

                    ], className="row mt-3")]))
        )
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("selected-csv-fields", "options"),
     Output("intermediate-value", "data")],
    [Input("selected-dir", "value")]
)
def get_all_csv(selector):
    """Get all the csv from the folder"""
    if selector is not None:
        csv_files = list(filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir(selector)))
        _DF = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(selector, f))
                         for f in csv_files])
        demo = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in _DF]
        return demo, _DF

    return []


@app.callback(
    Output("line-graph", "figure"),
    Output("stack-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("selected-csv-fields", "value"), Input("intermediate-value", "data")]
)
def update_graph(selector, done):
    """display the graph based on selected value."""
    if selector is not None:
        fig = px.line(done, x="Time", y=selector)
        stack = px.histogram(done, x="Time", y=selector, marginal="box",
                             hover_data=done)
        return fig, stack

    return {}, {}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I remove the  Output("intermediate-value", "data")] from get_all_csv() and Input("intermediate-value", "data") from update_graph(a, b) respectively it works fine. but when try to pass this parameters it gives me error

ERROR :
Callback error updating selected-csv-fields.options, intermediate-value.data